# CSS overlay close button responsive

Tags: html, css

I have this overlay and this overlay box and an overlay close button:

My issue with it, is that the close button is all over the place on Desktop, Tablet or Mobile. How can I fix this so that its always at the bottom right of the box. Here is the code:

```css
 .request-estimate {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 99999;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      display: none;
    }
    
    .request-estimate-box-container {
      top: 0%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 99999;
    }
    
    .request-estimate-box {
      display: none;
      height: 400px;
      width: 50%;
      background-color: #FFF;
      z-index: 99999;
      position: fixed;
      top: 5%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .request-estimate-close {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 99999;
      color: #FFF;
      bottom: 10%;
      font-size: 26px;
      left: 90%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div class="request-estimate" style="display: block;"></div>
    <div class="request-estimate-box-container">
      <div class="request-estimate-box" style="display: block;">
           <h1>Request Free Estimate</h1>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
         <p>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
         </p>
         <p>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
         </p>
         <p>
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control">
         </p>
         <p>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
         </p>
        </form>
         </div>
      <div class="request-estimate-close" style="display: block;"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Try wrap the content in a div with the css property postion: relative;

Comment: changing the postion to relative worked...put in an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Thank you very much, I made an answer now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrap the content in a div with the css property postion: relative;

Answer (score 0):

Add the close button's div in the box's div and make it float to the right. Check the code below:

Let me know if this doesnt answer your question.

```css
 .request-estimate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display: none;
}

.request-estimate-box-container {
  top: 0%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.request-estimate-box {
  display: none;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 99999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.request-estimate-close {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  color: #FFF;
  bottom: 5%;
  font-size: 26px;
  left: 80%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="request-estimate" style="display: block;"></div>
    <div class="request-estimate-box-container">
      <div class="request-estimate-box" style="display: block;">
           <h1>Request Free Estimate</h1>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
         <p>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
         </p>
         <p>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
         </p>
         <p>
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control">
         </p>
         <p>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
         </p>
        </form>

         </div>
      <div class="request-estimate-close" style="display: block; float:right;"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </div>
```

**UPDATE**

Since you want outside the box. I edited the code and set contained to position relative, let me know if still not working. It works for me.

Comment: but I am looking to have the close button outside the white box

Comment: btw you should also check to set your height of form and the x sign etc. When you make the page to a small window, it doesnt look good and no scroll bars appear. So need some work there